# Как пользуясь vk_api ловить payload с одинаковым началом

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, aiogram

Есть две inline кнопки.У обоих payload начинается одинаково, но заканчивается всегда по разному.Конец берется из базы данных, поэтому может быть вообще любым.Нужно, чтобы один хендлер ловил обе эти кнопки, а уже в теле функции проверял, какая именно кнопка была нажата.В aiogram это реализовано у меня так

```
dp.register_callback_handler(test_callback,lambda x: x.data and x.data.startswith('button_prefix '))
```

Но сейчас необходимо писать код для вк на библиотеке vk_maria, а там payload это словарь, а не строка.И как фильтровать словарь нет никаких идей.Пробовал все, что пришло в голову, пытался написать кастомный фильтр, но что-то не вышло.Под капотом библиотеки нашел какой-то PayloadFilter, как им пользоваться не понял...

Comment: В названии [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api), в тексте [vk_maria](https://github.com/lxstvayne/vk_maria), а в метках вообще [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram). Так что же у вас за библиотека?

Answer (score 0):

То, что ты делаешь в aiogram можно сделать и в vk_maria, используя [FunctionFilter](https://github.com/lxstvayne/vk_maria/blob/main/vk_maria/dispatcher/filters/filters.py#L89). По умолчанию работает через `f=...` в хендлере.

```py
@dp.message_handler(f=lambda x: ...)
def handler():
    ...
```